# yii CActiveRecord findAll with Error 500

Tags: php, yii

The Species model contains

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'samples' => array(self::HAS_MANY, 'Sample', 'species_id'),
    );
}
```

I want to get all samples belong to one specie

```
$species=  Species::model()->with('samples')->findAll(array('condition'=>'tax_id = :no','params'=>array(':no'=>$taxno)));
print_r($species);
$samples=$species->samples;  //error here
print_r($samples);
```

When I just `print_r($species)`, it shows the samples value inside. But it can't pass to `$samples` in  `$samples=$species->samples;` it shows the `error 500`.

Comment: What message is with this error?

Comment: you can post your table stracture.

Answer (score 0):

You are using **findAll** to get the data. So result will be in array format. You should use **for loop or foreach** to access the values.

```
foreach ($species as $specie) {
    echo $specie->samples;   
}
```

Using **find** will give only one record but **findAll** gives multiple records.

Answer (score 0):

you can change in your relationship in `Species.php` model.

**Species.php** model

```
public function relations()
{
    // NOTE: you may need to adjust the relation name and the related
    // class name for the relations automatically generated below.
    return array(
        'samples' => array(self::BELONGS_TO, 'Sample', 'species_id'),
    );
}
```

ControllerName.php file

```
$species=  Species::model()->with('samples')->findAll(array('condition'=>'tax_id = :no','params'=>array(':no'=>$taxno)));
echo "<pre>";
print_r($species);
//$samples=$species->samples; // You can not used direct object
//print_r($samples); //


foreach ($species as $key => $value) {
    echo "<pre>";
    echo "Species Object";
    print_r($value->attributes);
    echo "Samples Object";
    print_r($value->samples->attributes);
}
exit;
```